Ensuring \textheight image with respect the caption position
I try to create custom page layout which will fit to the Remarkable E-Ink display size. The document is formatted as a two column. Some images need to be placed over both columns. That's why I use float figure* in the \myImage macro.
The problem occurs when the images have an aspect ratio of 9x16. To demonstrate the behavior of the \myImage macro I used the example-image-16x9 image from the MWE package. To achieve a 9x16 aspect ratio I used the angle=90 parameter, which I don't use in the final macro.
At this image ratio, the image caption will overflow off the page. In other words, the image will use the entire height of the text area. How can I ensure that the \myImage macro provides enough space for the caption without having to manually scale the image to fit both elements in my page layout.

Figure 1 \myImage
MNWE:
\documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  twocolumn,
  open=any, 
  titlepage=false, 
  chapterprefix=on
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  verbose=true,                 % displays the parameter results on the terminal
  paperwidth  = 447pt,          % 157.10mm 
  paperheight = 595pt,          % 209.12mm 
  % landscape,                  %
  includehead, includefoot,     % include the head and foot into total body
  scale=1.0,                    %
  nomarginpar,                  % shrinks spaces for marginal notes to 0pt,
                                % \marginparwidth=0pt and \marginparwidth=0pt
  left=3pt, right=3pt,          % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
  top=0pt, bottom=11pt,         % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
  textwidth=441pt,              % Nastaví šířku textové oblasti na 441 bodů
  textheight=562pt,             % Nastaví výšku textové oblasti na 562 bodů; upravte podle potřeby
  headsep=2pt,                  %
  headheight=12pt,              % At least 11.0pt needed!! 
  showframe=true,              %
  nofoot,                       % noheadfoot=true, 
  heightrounded,                % better use it
]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{printlen}


\newcommand{\myImage}[4][0.8]{%
  \begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textheight,height=#1\textheight,keepaspectratio, angle=90]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
  \end{figure*}  
}


\begin{document}

  % Zobrazení hodnot textwidth a linewidth
  \begin{itemize}
    \item textwidth: \printlength\textwidth
    \item linewidth: \printlength\linewidth
    \item textheight: \printlength\textheight
  \end{itemize}

  \myImage[1]{example-image-16x9}{Example}{fig:example}

  \Blindtext

\end{document}

I also try to adopt the solution published for this question -> How to autoscale Figure Environment to fit page with text.
For next steps I took illustration from Illustration by Jonathan Burton as a test image for verification of the macro functionality.
First test of the original solution \autoscaleA:
As you can see on figure below, image is not placed correctly.
I undestood, that In LaTeX, when calculating the available height for an image, not only the height of the caption (\ht0) is subtracted, but also its depth (\dp0). The reason is that the caption may have parts of the text that extend below the baseline (such as subscripts or letters with descenders like “g” or “y”). This part of the text is called the depth.
Therefore, when calculating the available height for the image, we must consider the total height of the caption, which includes both the height above the baseline (\ht0) and the depth below the baseline (\dp0). This ensures that the image and caption fit on the page without overlapping or being cut off. But it is not happened in my macros \autoscaleA and \autoscaleB.
Here is an example of how it is calculated:
\dimen0: Total available height on the page.
\intextsep: Spacing around the image.
\ht0: Height of the caption.
\dp0: Depth of the caption.
The height of the image is then calculated as:
[ \text{Height of the image} = \dimen0 - \intextsep - \ht0 - \dp0 ]
This way, we ensure that the image has enough space on the page along with the caption.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\autoscaleA}[2]% #1 = image filename, #2 = caption
{\par\bgroup
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\dimen0][b]{\columnwidth}
    \def\@captype{figure}% or use \captionof{figure}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{#2}}% measure caption height
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \dimen0-\intextsep-\ht0-\dp0}]{#1}\par
    \unvbox0
  \end{minipage}%
\egroup\par}
\makeatother


Figure 2: First test
Second test of the modification \autoscaleB:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\autoscaleB}[2]% #1 = image filename, #2 = caption
{\par\bgroup
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax
  \begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \centering
    \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{#2}}% measure caption height
    \includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \dimen0-\intextsep-\ht0-\dp0}]{#1}\par
    \unvbox0
  \end{figure*}%
\egroup\par}
\makeatother


Figure 3: Second Test.
